# Is Stack Exchange built with WordPress and the WordPress QA plugin?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

The WordPress template and the new QA plugin is remarkably similar to the Stack Exchange family of sites. Although it does not have all the features of Stack Exchange, it does have all of the important ones. Is Stack Exchange just using the WordPress plugin?

Comment: If it were built using WP, you'd notice. It would be slower than a snail. :D (And this is coming from a long time WP junkie.)

Comment: If the plugin is new, if there is any relation between the two at all, the odds are its design is inspired by Stack Exchange not the other way around.

Comment: I agree. The good thing is we can create a stackoverflow site for under 70$ :)

Comment: See : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No it's not. All Stackexchange web sites are build on top of ASP.NET MVC I believe.

Comment: Correct. ASP.NET MVC.